# Get transit data from google maps api for android

Tags: java, javascript, android, google-maps

I'm making an app which shows the status of the road ( incidents or slow traffic, etc) and I'm using Google Maps as of now, the thing is I can't find if there's a way to get said status from the Android API? I know their JavaScript API shows a map in a HTML page and I could parse it and show it in a web view, but I'd like if there was a way in the Android API to do this.

So is there a way to get transit data using Google Maps Android API? If there's no way, how could I get the HTML from the JavaScript API and parse it to show it in a web view?

Comment: What do you want to show? A map or text data?

Comment: i want to show a map like the one they provide in the traffic layer.

Comment: Doesn't the setTrafficEnabled method on GoogleMap shows traffic info on your map? http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html

Comment: Oh cool, didn't read that part of the docs, thank you. Can you post this as an answer so the question can be closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call setTrafficEnabled method on GoogleMap and it will show traffic layer on your map
http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html